# Is it right to say "mutually exclusive with"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, prepositions, phrase-usage

Is it semantically correct to say Event A is mutually exclusive with Event B meaning the two cannot occur together? If not, which other preposition would fit in the phrase to convey the required meaning?

***mutually exculsive to / with / from*** ?

Comment: The normal usage would be "A and B are mutually exclusive". I can't ever remember hearing or seeing _mutually exclusive_ used with a preposition. The only sense in which _exclusive_ is normally used with a preposition is to indicate that the use of something is restricted to certain groups. For example "The Premier Bar is exclusive to First Class passengers"

Comment: "Mutually exclusive" is a term that *always* seems awkward if you try to say "A is mutually exclusive with/for/from/whatever B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mutual exclusivity trumps all

The two exist in a relationship of mutual exclusion. A excludes B, just as B excludes A. The relationship is imperative both ways. A preposition expresses relationship. The relationship of mutual exclusivity needs no further qualification. A preposition is not used in this case.

Comment: What is the correct wording though?

Comment: @wesm ‘Event ‘A’ and event ‘B’, being mutually exclusive, cannot be reconciled.

Comment: I agree that "A is mutually exclusive with B" doesn't work, but I'm not convinced the bidirectionality of the relationship explains why the preposition is problematic. Cf. "A is equivalent to B."

Comment: The proper form seems to be "A is mutually exclusive with respect to B". But that's a lot of chewing through words, so I like to use a more concise form ("with") since _people know what you mean_. This is probably an area where English is evolving.

Comment: They are exclusive to each other, which is why the modifier (mutual-Lt.)

Comment: Ok, so excessive wordplay aside, is it mutually exclusive to / with / from? Non-native speakers like myself ask these questions because it's legit hard to figure this stuff out when you don't have natural intuition of the language.

Answer (score 2):

I did see attested examples from expert writers of "A be mutually exclusive with B".
And I'll wager people can easily understand the intended meaning,
thought I am not a grammar expert myself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This would benefit from including those examples.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].